# Python module for longlong types

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to make a `int64_t` module for python because python doesn't have a `long long` type. I found one in `ctypes` but I can't use it.
So, I have embedded an intro in my application so the best way is to create a module that returns `int64_t` from c++.

```
PyObject *Py_int64_t(PyObject *poSelf, PyObject *poArgs)
{
    return Py_BuildNone();
}
static PyMethodDef s_methods[] =
{
    {"Py_int64_t", Py_int64_t, METH_VARARGS}
}
```

The problem is I don't know from where to start. As you can see Py_int64_t main function is empty. I need some examples about how should I construct that function.

Comment: Is this just for interacting with C/C++ code that uses 64-bit ints, or are you actually trying to make a Python type for 64-bit ints that will only be used in pure Python code?  If the latter, there's no need for it, as Python integers have arbitrary precision.

Comment: Will be used in pure python code.

Comment: For pure Python you don't *need* 64-bit ints, they're already unlimited in size. Use 1024-bit numbers if you want.